# GNOME3 extension collapse,how to solve it, or make GNOME3 to default?

Tags: gnome, extension

I tried to install an extension(auto hide top panel) in extensions.gnome.org,

but then it get something wrong and looks like this,
[image]

look at the first one, obviously right,

I've tried reboot or re-install the extension, didn't help,

so how to solve with this?

I'm using 11.10 and gnome 3.2.

Comment: install gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: I'm actually using it, but didn't help. This collapsed extension didn't appear in the tweak-tool's list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that extension is not active on E.G.O. any longer, I would first assume you manually installed it, and perhaps the installation was corrupted somehow.

I first suggest to remove it by running the following

`sudo rm -R .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/autohidetopbar2@werewolves.us`

If this doesn't work it was probably somehow installed system wide, so try

`sudo rm -R /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/autohidetopbar2\@werewolves.us/`

and then possibly try to reinstall it, you may need to first restart the shell though, so either logout and login, restart your system, or do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

To reinstall it, basically you should just right click it and extract it, then the easy way is to keep this folder open and do the following.

Now run <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and paste

`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> or by right click, paste.

Then either right click and copy the extension directory "extension_folder@domain", this directory is the one that contains the extension.js and metadata.json, now paste it into the other folder `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` or just drag it there.

Next you have to restart the shell by running <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it should be available. Once I know the details of the extension I can provide alternate instructions, but this is the easiest way.

Comment: well,I get a tar.gz from author's site, but how to manually install it with tweak-tool?

Comment: I have updated the original answer with details on reinstalling, but if you could also provide a link to the extension where you downloaded it that will help provide alternate installation instructions.

Comment: As for using tweak tool, the compressed file must be a zip file and the extension.js and metadata.json must be in the top level when you open this archive, they can not be inside a folder in the archive.